# DateValue equivalent that works in SQL when some records can do a valid conversion and others not?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a set of date where some of the records have a valid convertible to date text field and other records which are not. For example, **"1/1/2019"**, next record may be **"January 1, 1919"**, next may be **"pre-2010"**, etc.

I need to convert the valid values to a date field.

In MSAccess I can do an update, Set `DateField` to `DateValue(txtDateField)` to convert the rows that work to convert. Access would leave `DateField` as Null for the bad non date type text, but convert the good rows, which is the majority.

How do I do this in SQL? I have tried the convert or cast function but it errors out in update or even select because some of the rows aren't valid. How do I select the valid rows?

Also, FYI, I don't even know what the data values actually are. I just need to convert the ones which are valid and leave the ones with bad values as they are.

Basically user form allowed entry of text into a field which they now want to search on by date. The good values can be easily converted in Access via the `DateValue` function, any way to do it in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server, you can use `IsDate`.

Comment: Edit: Found it. I can use a where clause with the IsDate() function to only run the convert or cast when IsDate(txtDateField) = 1